# Cannot sendAction to route from component in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to send an action up through two components to my route where I will fire a createRecord action. I have been console.logging up through the chain but I never seem to make it to the route. Here is the code for my route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  store: this.get('store'),
  actions: {
    createEvent (concert) {
      debugger;
      console.log(concert, 'events route');
      console.log(this.get('store'));
      let events = this.get('store').createRecord(concert);
      return events.save();
    }
  }
});
```

and my route template:

```
{{display-search-results creatEvent="createEvent"}}
```

The subsequent components/component-templates, in sequential order are:

**display-search-results temp:**

```
{{thumbnail-for-search-results event=event createEvent="createEvent"}}
```

**display-search-results component:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['col-md-3'],
  actions: {
    createEvent(concert) {
      console.log(concert, "display-search-results comp");
      this.sendAction('createEvent', concert);
    }
  }
});
```

**thumbnail-for-search-results temp:**

```
<img class='event-pic' src={{event.image_url}} onError="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/r7UiMQr.png';">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="thumb-title">{{event.title}}</h3>
        <p class="event-description">
           {{event.venue_name}} <br> {{event.start_time}} <br> <br>{{event.city_name}} <br>
           {{event.region_name}} <br>{{event.country_name}}
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button"{{action "createEvent" concert on="click"}}>>Add Event</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
     </div>
```

**thumbnail-for-search-results component:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['thumbnail'],
  // concert: this.get('store').find('eventful-event'),
  actions: {
    createEvent() {
      console.log(this.get('event'), "thumb comp")
      this.sendAction('createEvent', this.get('event'));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: show usage for your component, please

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk Which component?

Comment: DZ already help you)

Comment: Why don't you remove store: this.get('store'), you don't need that...

Comment: Routes aren't connected to the templates, you need to move the handler to the controller, or use the `ember-route-action` addon.

Answer (score 0):

I think the action name which your firing is wrong, it is createEvent, not create record. I have created an ember twiddle for interacting from component to route action.

Here u can check https://ember-twiddle.com/a81fbae955602bd9ed375995014c9fe6?openFiles=components.display-search-results.js%2Ctemplates.components.thumbnail-for-search-results.hbs

Comment: I'm not sure where you think I'm making the mistake. Where should I change createRecord to createEvent? In my route?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because of the typo here:

```
{{display-search-results creatEvent="createEvent"}}
```

Use `createEvent` instead of `creatEvent`

Comment: Thank you that, was a mistake. It didn't fix the problem tho. The typo happened when trying to get things to work and changing naming around.

Comment: I have modified the twiddle given by @prudvi to work. Fixing the typo fixed the error. You can look at it here: https://ember-twiddle.com/15e7f89a092ba8b057f2f6a79870705a